# VS Code inserts <tab> when tab to autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code

This just started happening yesterday when I updated VS Code for Mac to 1.19.0.

Hitting the tab key to autocomplete inserts the actual string `<tab>` in my code; I have to hit `enter` to accept the autocomplete suggestion now.

Ex: (pipe is the cursor)

```
Forms| //autocomplete includes 'FormsModule'
(hitting the tab key results in)
Forms<tab>
```

Answer (score 2):

Turned out it was a problem with the Vim extension, which has this keymap:

```
  {
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "extension.vim_tab",
    "when": "editorFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl && vim.mode != 'Insert'"
  },
```

So I just negated it:

```
  {
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "-extension.vim_tab",
    "when": "editorFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl && vim.mode != 'Insert'"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vim extension i recomend you using this in your keybindings

```
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "tab",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorTabMovesFocus && vim.mode != 'Insert'"
},
{
    "key": "shift+tab",
    "command": "outdent",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorTabMovesFocus"
}
```

That way you can still using your tab to indentation but the  `vim.mode != 'Insert'` prevents it from not working in for completion.